# concatenate cells based on other range criterias

Tags: vba, excel

I need to concatenate cells in Range "B" based on criteria for range "A" & "C". Initially I was trying to code out using Arrays to store value but doesn't seem to work.

**For example:**

Criteria excel:

[image]

Outcome:

[image]

Based on the example, the outcome should be reflected with first criteria of range"C" (date) then follow by concatenated results(Range "B") based on second criteria range"A"

Comment: You can use an array and a dictionary inside another dictionary. This way you can avoid duplication of your entries and organise your data as you described. For demonstration purposes: `{'3/4/2018':{'ugly duckinling':(1,2,3)}, '4/4/2018':{'ugly duckinling':(4), 'Disney stories':(5), 'chicken soup':(6, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)}}`. I demonstrated an array as `()` and dictionary as `{}`.

Comment: @Tehscript Didn't see your comment until after my answer but that's exactly what I've done below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the below. This may look fairly ugly as I'm using what I call a `major` dictionary and `minor` dictionaries. The `major` dictionary uses your date field for it's key values and holds the `minor` dictionaries as items. The `minor` dictionaries consist of your title field for the keys and have a value of an `Array` which in turn stores the chapter numbers individually as values.

There are many other ways to achieve what you're looking for, and also probably many simpler ways to do so. Personally my preferred way is how I've approached it as it allows me to access each element of my data at any time before I write it back to the sheet. The benefit of this is I can go on to do further tasks with the data fairly easily if I so choose (e.g. I could sort alphabetically, by number of chapters etc. etc.). Where as I may struggle to do this with an already concatenated string.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TransposeAndGroupData()
    Dim arr As Variant, tmp As Variant
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim k, v

    ' Create major dictionary
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' Change to your sheet reference
    With ActiveSheet
        '' INPUT

        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 3)).Value2

        '' INITIAL PROCESSING

        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            ' Test if date exists in major dictionary, if not add value to dictionary and initiate minor dictionary
            If Not dict.exists(arr(i, 3)) Then dict.Add Key:=(arr(i, 3)), Item:=CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            ' Test if title exists in minor dictionary
            ' Add if not
            If Not dict(arr(i, 3)).exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
                ' Initiate array for chapters
                ReDim tmp(0)
                tmp(0) = arr(i, 2)
                ' Add to minor dictionary if title doesn't exist and add array
                dict(arr(i, 3)).Add Key:=arr(i, 1), Item:=tmp
            ' Update if exists
            Else
                ' We can't write directly to the minor dictionaries array so we first write it into a temp array before writing back
                tmp = dict(arr(i, 3))(arr(i, 1))
                ReDim Preserve tmp(LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp) + 1)
                tmp(UBound(tmp)) = arr(i, 2)
                dict(arr(i, 3))(arr(i, 1)) = tmp
            End If
        Next i

        ''OUTPUT

        ' Update to the first cell of where you want the destination for your data
        With .Cells(1, 5)
            ' Loop through major dictionary to generate headers
            For Each k In dict.keys
                ' Output date as heading
                .Offset(0, j).Value2 = k
                ' Set number format (Dates will be handled as longs and will output as such)
                .Offset(0, j).NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
                i = 0
                ReDim tmp(1 To dict(k).Count)
                ' Loop through minor dictionary to generate value
                For Each v In dict(k).keys
                    i = i + 1
                    tmp(i) = v & ": " & Join(dict(k)(v), ", ")
                Next v
                .Offset(1, j).Value2 = Join(tmp, vbNewLine)
                j = j + 1
            Next k
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Plus 1. Least I can do as I borrowed your method for output into single cell with newLine.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure how one would list them out with new lines in between in a single cell but you can collect them up as follows

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub StoryWithSoup()

    With Worksheets("Sheet11") 'change as required
        Dim arr(), i As Long
        arr = .UsedRange.Value
        Dim dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not dict.exists(arr(i, 3)) Then dict.Add arr(i, 3), CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Next i

        For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not dict(arr(i, 3)).exists((arr(i, 1))) Then
                dict(arr(i, 3)).Add arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2)
            Else
                dict(arr(i, 3))(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 3))(arr(i, 1)) & "," & arr(i, 2)
            End If
        Next i

        Dim key As Variant
        For Each key In dict.keys
            Dim key2 As Variant
            For Each key2 In dict(key).keys
                Debug.Print key & " : " & key2 & ": " & dict(key)(key2)
            Next key2
        Next key   
    End With  
End Sub
```

Output:

[image: Output]

**Edit:**

Learning from @Tom's answer (to credit to him for how to put in a single cell) , I can use his method to output into single cells

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub StoryWithSoup()

    With Worksheets("Sheet11") 'change as required
        Dim arr(), i As Long
        arr = .UsedRange.Value
        Dim dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not dict.exists(arr(i, 3)) Then dict.Add arr(i, 3), CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Next i

        For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not dict(arr(i, 3)).exists((arr(i, 1))) Then
                dict(arr(i, 3)).Add arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2)
            Else
                dict(arr(i, 3))(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 3))(arr(i, 1)) & "," & arr(i, 2)
            End If
        Next i

         With .Cells(1, 5)
            Dim k As Variant, tmp(), j As Long
           .Resize(1, dict.Count) = dict.keys
            For Each k In dict.keys
                i = 0
                ReDim tmp(1 To dict(k).Count)
                Dim v As Variant
                For Each v In dict(k).keys
                    i = i + 1
                    tmp(i) = v & ":" & dict(k)(v)                    
                Next v
                .Offset(1, j).Value2 = Join(tmp, vbNewLine)
                j = j + 1
            Next k
        End With     
    End With    
End Sub
```